# How can I get a list of files that are used by an average sized web app

Tags: javascript, html

I have an averaged size web app that has HTML, CSS, png, and Javascript files that make up the front-end portion.  I am using a service worker to add the ability for my app to work when not online.  I must provide the service worker with a list of the files it needs to cache but I don't know how to tell what files I actually need.  When you install packages with npm you also get a bunch of stuff you don't need, so I can't just cache everything.

I know the network tab of the browser debug window shows what is actually being loaded, but that's too tedious.  Is there some way I can automate this?

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into five headaches:

1. Not all browsers fully support service workers and caching
2. Service worker and cache item versioning can be painful (example: if v2 deletes items from v1 and a v1 user comes back online at v3 which no longer has the deletes, ...)
3. There are browser limits on cache size
4. Browsers sometimes clean out caches when other apps/sites use a lot of storage
5. As you've identified, you need a definite and manageable list

Although this does not answer your explicit question, there is a suggestion that might limit your pain, to wit: before adding files to your service worker caching, set `cache-control` and `expires` headers and build in logic to fail gracefully if your user experiences a cache miss while offline -- see [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

Once you have the cache control set up, from the network tab in your browser's Dev Tools, you'll see different status codes for resources that are loaded from device cache, this is your starting list for caching.

From there you can do something like the following in the console to exploit the Performance API to generate a list of files

```
window.performance
  .getEntriesByType("resource")
  .forEach( (resource) => console.log( resource.name ) );
```

Comment: 1. I'm only targeting Chrome
3. My app is not too big
4.  See 3
Isn't one of the main purposes of service workers to solve the off-line problem>

Comment: Yes. But try the weather app demo that's in Google's samples. Use it once. Wait a month. Disconnect your device and run it. Caching isn't forever. It's a fallback. Jake Archibald has some (old) samples for different patterns

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you right-click on the contents of the Network tab of the Chrome browser debug window you have a choice of "Save as HAR with content".  This will save an XML file showing all the resources loaded.  Then do:

```
grep '"url":' xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.har
```

and you get a complete list of resources.